# Using Python APIs on ipage?

Tags: python, api

I was wondering, I'm interested in using the Python Yahoo Finance API on my website, I'm using iPage as my webhost, how can I install APIs there, I just today found out how can I code the website using python

Answer (score 0):

You will need to copy the scripts to your **/cgi-bin/ directory**.

You can find further reference in your iPage Control Panel, under "**Additional Resources/CGI and Scripted Language Support**". Then look for "**Server Side Includes and CGI**", and you will find the supported Python version and  other relevant directory paths for your setup.